# Get disk size minus reserved space

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, powershell, child-process

The value of `size` that `wmic logicaldisk get size` returns is basically the advertised size of the hard drive. However, I am trying to obtain the total disk size minus the reserved space.

Since I could not figure out how to retrieve this value from `diskpart` `list disk` without launching an actual instance of command prompt, I am now trying to obtain it from PowerShell with the code below.

```
cp.exec('get-volume', {'shell': 'powershell.exe'}, (error, stdout)=>{
  console.log(stdout)
})

DriveLetter FriendlyName FileSystemType DriveType HealthStatus OperationalStatus SizeRemaining      Size
----------- ------------ -------------- --------- ------------ ----------------- -------------      ----
D           [removed]    NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK                    930.74 GB 930.91 GB
C           System       NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK                    520.67 GB 930.88 GB
                         NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK                    112.01 MB    450 MB
            Recovery     NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK                    109.23 MB    529 MB
            Recovery     NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK                     73.03 MB    499 MB
```

The problem is that when the PowerShell query is narrowed to `get-volume | format-list size`, it reverts to returning the advertised size of the disk.

```
size : 999558213632 // basically 1TB instead of 930 GB
```

---

Why does it revert back to the advertised size?

**Does anybody know how I can obtain the practical size of the disk (i.e. 930 GB)?**

Comment: Take a look at this post because your question seem to be more related to ps than to nodejs https://stackoverflow.com/q/12159341/10707187

Comment: @R.LM that is actually the one im already looking at lol. i found one string that worked: `Get-CimInstance win32_logicaldisk | where caption -eq "D:" | foreach-object {write "$($_.Size/1gb)"}`

Comment: @R.LM for some reason if you type `1mb` into PowerShell, the value it returns is `1048576` instead of `1000000`. im dumbfounded

Comment: Lovely windows lol

Comment: @R.LM lol and of course the values for `1gb`, `1tb`, etc are all wonky too. no wonder all of this has been so goddamn confusing :/

Comment: Actually Powershell calculates that correct ...  take a look at this: [Byte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte) ... and pay attention to the unit multiples!

Comment: @Olaf wow youre right. its because Windows is of course binary. does Linux also calculate it in a binary base?

Comment: @R.LM [check this out](https://superuser.com/questions/1513829/wonky-size-units-in-powershell-windows/1513830#1513830) does linux or unix calculate it differently than windows?

Comment: Thanks about that @oldboy, i didn’t know about that

Comment: @Olaf so is 1TB equal to 1024GBs in a binary system? lastly, why are the unit sizes called the same things in diff base number systems? is 1TB in binary considered equal to 1TB in decimal?

Comment: @R.LM np! are you on linux or unix? if so, do they treat numbers in the binary or decimal system?

Comment: As far as i know both unix and windows uses binary systems. They are based on bytes (2^3) and everything is treated as binary (ascii is 128 characters which is 2^7 and so on) but when it comes to the way the bash command has been developed i don’t know really much.

Comment: @R.LM super interesting. yeah its weird cuz i know computers r based on binary, and id always see numbers like 128, 1024, etc, but it never clicked that thats because it is all based on binary if that makes any sense. do u know if 1TB in decimal is considered equal to 1TB in binary or am i thinking about this wrongly?

Comment: 1 *tera*byte is (canonically) *always* 1000 *giga*bytes = 1 000 000 *mega*bytes = 1 000 000 000 *kilo*bytes = 1 000 000 000 bytes. There is a different measure for base-2 sizes: 1  *tebi*byte (TiB) = 1024 *gibi*bytes (GiB) = 1 048 576 *mebi*bytes (MiB) = 1 073 741 824 *kibi*bytes (KiB) = 1 099 511 627 776 bytes. Windowsis simply lying to you when it says KB, MB, GB, TB but means KiB, MiB, GiB, TiB. Check [Wikipedia on binary prefixes and inconsistencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix#Inconsistent_use_of_units)

Comment: **Voted to close.** The question in the title differs from the question at the bottom of the content, nevertheless both questions (including the discussion [1024 vs 1000](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/kb-1024-vs-1000/)) can be found in many other questions (search for e.g. [`PowerShell GB`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=powershell+gb)) and the common solution for [**Does anybody know how I can obtain the practical size of the disk (i.e. 930 GB)?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57535324/1701026).

Comment: @iRon since when did SO turn into merely a forum to discuss programming concepts? i thought SO was about asking questions about stuff you dont know to learn about the stuff you dont know...

Comment: The reason that I voted to close has nothing to do with either  a programming concept or asking questions but because the possible answers were already supplied in several similar questions. If still think your question isn't answered anywere else, I recommend to create a new question and possible refer to similar questions and were they don't specifically answer yours.

Comment: @iRon the initial reason was that the title of the question and the question asked at the end were different...